# Why debugger shows problem before sorting?

Tags: c++

I have problem with my program written  in C. I want to draw int numbers to 2-size array, show it and then sort numbers in lines, and then make transposition with array, but it doesn't work. debugger show error in line with printf in function main() but i totally don't know what's wrong.
Thank for all support.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <algorithm>//dla swapa
void draw(int **tab, int m, int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            tab[m][n] = rand() % (100 + 1); //0-100
        }
    }
}


void sort(int **tab, int m, int n)
{
    m = 0;
    while (m) 
    {
        for (int j = n - 1; j > 0; j--) 
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {

                if (tab[i] > tab[i + 1])
                {
                    std:: swap(tab[i], tab[i + 1]);
                }
            }
        }
        m++;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            printf("|%d||[%d|\n", tab[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    int w, k;
    int **tab;
    printf("Lines: ");
    scanf(" %d", &w);
    printf("columns: ");
    scanf(" %d", &k);

    tab = (int**)malloc(w*sizeof(int*));
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        tab[i] = (int*)malloc(k * sizeof(int));
    }
    printf("\nBefore sorting: \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < w; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < k; i++)
        {
            printf("|%d||%d|", tab[i][j]);
        }
    }
    // lub     tab=(int*)malloc(w*k*sizeof(int));
    srand(time(NULL));
    draw(tab, w, k);
    printf("\nSorted array:\n");
    sort(tab,w,k);

}
```

Comment: That's ... not C.

Comment: "debugger show error in line with printf in functiion main()" - the format string expects two integer values, but you're only providing one.

Comment: "_debugger show error in line with printf in function main()_" and yet you didn't quote the error (and which debugger provided it), nor specify at which of the many `printf()`s in `main()` it occurs... I'm voting to close because "_it doesn't work_" is not a problem description, and what is here requires too much guesswork from readers.

Comment: Stop writing C in C++, use containers.

Comment: Besides, the purpose of a debugger is not to "show errors". A debugger enables you to step through the code and view the paths that are taken and the values of objects in scope - and therefore to check that, at every stage, the program is doing what you expect it to do - or if not, whatever it *is* doing instead, so you can see what you need to fix. As well as not having an error, we don't have any evidence that you've tried to actually use your debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The line `for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {` should be `for (int i = 0; i < w; ++i)`
2. The line `printf("|%d||%d|", tab[i][j]);` should be `printf("tab[%d][%d] = %d\n", i, j, tab[i][j]);`
3. Your function `sort()` is wrong.
4. You should use like `row`, `col` not `w`, `k`

The following `code` could work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <algorithm>

void draw(int **tab, int row, int col) {
  for (int i = 0; i < row; ++i)
    for (int j = 0; j < col; ++j)
      tab[i][j] = rand() % (100 + 1);
}

void sort(int **tab, int row, int col) {
  int x = 0;
  int y = 0;
  while (x != row) {
    int temp = tab[x][y];
    for (int j = y + 1; j != col; ++j)
      if (tab[x][j] < tab[x][y])
        std::swap(tab[x][j], tab[x][y]);
    for (int i = x + 1; i != row; ++i)
      for (int j = 0; j != col; ++j)
        if (tab[i][j] < tab[x][y])
          std::swap(tab[i][j], tab[x][y]);
    ++y;
    if (y == col) {
      y = 0;
      ++x;
    }
  }
}

void output(int** tab, int row, int col) {
  for (int i = 0; i < row; ++i)
    for (int j = 0; j < col; ++j)
      printf("tab[%d][%d] = %d\n", i, j, tab[i][j]);
}

int main() {
  int row, col;
  int **tab;
  printf("Lines: ");
  scanf(" %d", &row);
  printf("columns: ");
  scanf(" %d", &col);

  tab = (int **)malloc(row * sizeof(int *));
  for (int i = 0; i < row; ++i)
    tab[i] = (int *)malloc(col * sizeof(int));
  printf("\nBefore sorting: \n");
  srand(time(NULL));
  draw(tab, row, col);
  output(tab, row, col);
  printf("\nSorted array:\n");
  sort(tab, row, col);
  output(tab, row, col);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following lines (it appears twice):

```
printf("|%d||[%d|\n", tab[i][j]);
```

Wants to print two numbers but you are only giving it a single value `tab[i][j]` to print.

You also need to look at this code:

```
   tab = (int**)malloc(w*sizeof(int*));
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        tab[i] = (int*)malloc(k * sizeof(int));
    }
```

Here you allocate `w` array elements but then use `k`when in the for loop.

Comment: OK, i change it printf("|%d|\n", tab[i][j]); but the problem is still.